# ios setting up ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to incorporate ASIHTTPRequest in my iOS project however the link everyone is citing for setup instructions is down: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions . Currently in my iOS project I am getting an error for library not found on import ASIHTTPRequest.h . I cannot find the setup instructions anywhere else online. Can anyone provide some guidance here?

Edit: I have tried downloading all ASI files and going to "add files" in my project and incorporating them. However, when i do this- almost all of the imported files are highlighted as having errors.

Comment: You should really go back to iOS4. Is there are a reason you're using `ASIHTTPRequest` after it has been discontinued?

Comment: I'm working on a small project and it seems to be by far the most simple to use for passing data to a php web service which will in turn update a mysql database

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` should not be used in new work, for similar capabilities use `AFNetworking` which is currently being maintained.

Comment: @jeremy Understood. If its simple, use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` (or `AFNetworking` if you want to use a third-party library).

Comment: As I am on a deadline and very familiar with asihttprequest, can no one provide insight into how to incorporate this into the project

Comment: Ah, a deadline is always a justification for writing bad code? Seriously: Writing bad code is not a good way to advance your career.

Comment: @jeremy I would agree with Zaph. Technical debt is a nightmare. If you really insist on the [documentation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Aallseeing-i.com%2FASIHTTPRequest%2FSetup-instructions&oq=cache%3Aallseeing-i.com%2FASIHTTPRequest%2FSetup-instructions&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS563US563&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1782j0j4&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.91071109,d.b2w&biw=1364&bih=740&dpr=2&ech=1&psi=_9o2VZrNHoLVsAW98oHwCg.1429658368206.3&ei=_9o2VZrNHoLVsAW98oHwCg&emsg=NCSR&noj=1), prefix that URL by `cache:`.